# grails maven integration

Tags: grails, maven, ivy

Most of the projects I have worked on in grails have involved using the STS plugin in eclipse.  For grails projects, is it common to use maven? Or is it more common to just use something like Ivy for dependency management and use grails to build/deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used grails project with maven, when it didn't have own dependency resolution. Was ok,  but had problems with command line commands (like `mvn grails:run-app` instead of `grails run-app`, and it was more annoying when we need to pass a parameter)

But current Grails can download all dependencies, from Maven or Ivy repositories. Without any external tool, just Ivy as a library, see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#ivy

So, I don't see any reason of using anything special, like external maven or ivy

Comment: Thanks, Igor. That was the impression that I was getting but you have confirmed.

Comment: @Igor Artamonov Yeah, this seems like a good suggestion.  I was looking to add the xuggler dependencies to my Grails project, and it is highly maven-centric.  Didn't realize grails dep management could grok maven repos.  Thanks.